# All cells on UITableview change when I try to create a new one

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create an iOS app in which I must have a UITableView that every time I press a new entry button, a  newcell appears with the time when I pressed that button. My problem is that everytime I press the buttons, not only the cell which is created displays the current time, but the cells above it, which were showing a different time, reload and also show the current time. To try and explain it better, if I press the button at 8:05, 9:01 and 9:10, i want the UITableView to show:

```
-8:05
-9:01
-9:10
```

Instead, it's showing:

```
-9:10
-9:10
-9:10.
```

What do I do?? Thanks

Here's my code ( newEntry is the button and brain is an object where I have the method to get the current time)

```
@implementation MarcaPontoViewController{

    NSMutableArray *_entryArray;
@synthesize brain=_brain;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _brain = [[Brain alloc] init];
    _entryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //[self updateTime];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
    }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_entryArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_entryArray lastObject];
           }

    return cell;
}


- (IBAction)newEntry:(id)sender {


    [_entryArray addObject:[self.brain currentTime]];


    [_timeTable reloadData];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here in this line :

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [_entryArray lastObject];
```

You need to use :

```
cell.textLabel.text = [_entryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Or,

```
cell.textLabel.text = _entryArray[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your help is very much apreciated. It's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

The line `cell.textLabel.text = [_entryArray lastObject]` will only ever return the last object in the array, which is why you are seeing the same time repeated. Change this to:

```
// in cellForRowAtIndexPath:
cell.textLabel.text = [_entryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This should fix the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

[_entryArray lastObject] always gives the last returned object.

Use

```
cell.textLabel.text = [_entryArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```